# Is there a Ruby version of for-loop similar to the one on Java/C++?

Tags: java, ruby, foreach, for-loop

Is there a Ruby version of for-loop similar to the one in Java/C(++)?

In Java:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The reason is because I need to do different operations based on the index of the iteration. Looks like Ruby only has a for-each loop?

Am I correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can use each_with_index

```
collection = ["element1", "element2"]
collection.each_with_index {|item,index| puts item; puts index}
```

the 'index' variable gives you the element index during each iteration

Answer (score 15):

Ruby tends to use iterators rather than loops; you can get all the function of loops with Ruby's powerful iterators.

There are several choices to do this, let's assume you have an array 'arr' of size 1000.

```
1000.times {|i| puts arr[i]}
0.upto(arr.size-1){|i| puts arr[i]}
arr.each_index {|i| puts arr[i]}
arr.each_with_index {|e,i| puts e} #i is the index of element e in arr
```

All these examples provide the same functionality

Comment: I would add that you can also use a for loop, as in: for i in (0...arr.length); puts arr[i]; end

Answer (score 11):

How about `step`?

```
0.step(1000,2) { |i| puts i }
```

is equivalent to:

```
for (int i=0; i<=1000; i=i+2) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The while loop executes its body zero or more times as long as its condition is true.

```
while <condition>
    # do this
end
```

The while loop can substitute the 'for' loop of Java. 
In Java,

```
for (initialization;, condition;, incrementation;){
    //code 
}
```

is same as following (except, in the second form, initialized variables are not local to for-loop).

```
initialization;
for(, condition;, ) {
    //code
    incrementation;
}
```

The ruby 'while' loop can be written in this form to work as for-loop of Java. In Ruby,

```
initialization;
while(condition)
    # code
    incrementation;
end
```

Note that the 'while' (and 'until' and 'for') loop doesn't introduce a new scope; previously existing locals can be used in the loop, and new locals created will be available afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

In Ruby, the `for` loop may be implemented as:

```
1000.times do |i|
  # do stuff ...
end
```

If you want both the element and the index then the `each_with_index` syntax is probably best:

```
collection.each_with_index do |element, index|
  # do stuff ...
end
```

However the `each_with_index` loop is slower since it provides both the `element` and `index` objects for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: `each_with_index` is not slower than doing an array lookup for each element. It should be quite a bit faster.

Comment: Correct, but if you don't perform the array lookup for every iteration of the loop, `each_with_index` may be slower.  It ultimately depends on the loop of course.

Comment: Well, yes, if you're not using an array, obviously you won't want to use an array method...

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in 0..100 do
  #bla bla
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user [each with index](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003137).

Answer (score 1):

when i just need the numbers (and not wanting to iterate) I prefer this:

```
(0..10000).each do |v|
    puts v
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`times` is recommended over `each_with_index`. `times` is around 6 times faster. Run the code below.

```
require "benchmark"

TESTS = 10_000_000
array = (1..TESTS).map { rand }
Benchmark.bmbm do |results|
  results.report("times") do
    TESTS.times do |i|
      # do nothing
    end
  end

  results.report("each_with_index") do
    array.each_with_index do |element, index|
      # Do nothing
    end
  end
end
```

I got the result as below with my MacBook (Intel Core2Duo).

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------------
times             1.130000   0.000000   1.130000 (  1.141054)
each_with_index   7.550000   0.210000   7.760000 (  7.856737)
------------------------------------------ total: 8.890000sec

                      user     system      total        real
times             1.090000   0.000000   1.090000 (  1.099561)
each_with_index   7.600000   0.200000   7.800000 (  7.888901)
```

Comment: you are not accessing the array elements in the 'times' benchmark - you are comparing an array lookup with an empty loop